# Android Mobile warning: mysql_connect(); access denied for user 'root@localhost'

Tags: php, android, mysql-connect

I am using android mobile LG 445 model. I installed palapa web server. I am getting warning when I am running my php code for connecting mysql database. The Warning is that **warning: mysql_connect(); Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'(using password: NO).** So, is there any password for localhost in android mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Default mysql password is: adminadmin

Right from Play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alfanla.android.pws&hl=en

Comment: Thanks so much. I used this "adminadmin" password. Now I can connect mysql.